# How to execute multiple rails commands when creating a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to execute the following rails commands when creating a new rails app.

```
rails new xx -d mysql
rails g model Post name:string
rails g model User name:string
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I don't know how to make it due to lack of ruby ​​knowledge.
let me know quick tips on how to make it if you know.
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Why can't you write this as a shell script or Rake task?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You haven't showed us where you researched or what you tried, or what went wrong. Without that information it looks like you didn't do those things and want us to write the code or a tutorial for you, either of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the commands you listed, I would recommend reading up on the [Rails Application Template API](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html). You will be able to put your generators, migrations, and more in there.

An example template with your requirements could be like this:

```
# template.rb
generate(:model, "Post name:string")
generate(:model, "User name:string")
rails_command("db:create")
rails_command("db:migrate")
```

Then you would call the following to build your new app with your template

```
rails new xx -m ./template.rb
```

Comment: No need for "EDIT:". My advice: think of writing answers as writing an article. You may go through various drafts, possibly adopting suggestions offered by readers of those drafts, with the objective of producing a polished final text. Also, if you revise an answer to incorporate suggestions made in a comment, and wish to recognize and thank the author of the comment, do so in a comment, not in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a gem—but with a [rakefile](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/02/ruby-rake/), perhaps.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's a link, and should have been a comment.